# Creating login form with PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am beginner in all this and i am trying to learn. I am creating simple login form using php, mysqli. I have created database with all information need it. I have chosen bellow php code to try to login user on my page, but what is happening is that after putting correct email and password it just takes me back to same page (index.php) like it seems information are not correct but i know it is as i put them myself in database, it just doesn't want to take me to next page(home.php). Can some one please take look of my code and see what i am doing wrong. Thank you.

Login form (index.php):

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="login_process.php">
 <input type="text" name="email" size="15" placeholder="email" required="required" />
 <input type="password" name="password" size="15" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
 <input id="loginButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />
 </form>
```

db_config.php:

```
define("DBHOST", "localhost");
define("DBUSER", "root");
define("DBPASS", "");
define("DBNAME", "aroundtheworld");
```

login_process.php:

```
require("db_config.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password));

if($hash != $userData['password']){
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: Please, start using PDO and prepared statements.
Try to debug step by step what you are getting from mysqli_num_rows.

Comment: @dariusz.g PDO isn't mandatory, mysqli is ok ...

Comment: if would be good if you check for errors with mysqli_error().

Comment: @ClementMalet, you're right, but it's a step forward to use PDO.

Comment: using `if($hash == $userData['password']){    header("Location: home.php");    }else{    header("Location: index.php");    }` will be good than your current structure

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha, thank you for answer, i do as you suggested then still same is happening, but if i leave != if statement and switch headers as you suggested then i can go to next page (home.php) but i can proceed to next page even if I put incorrect email and username. Do you know why?

Comment: @Ronin you need to keep that if statement to authenticate the user with the password. What i said is only redirect to home.php when the password matches with the `$hash`.
To solve your problem, you can `echo values` where you need to check if values are there. and use `mysqli_error()` to see errors if occurred. try to troubleshoot your problem and ask with what you get

Comment: maybe your "password" column store less data in your database. check with the sign up page and see there has the same algorithm for password encryption and also check whether full encrypted password length is less than your "password" column string length in your database

Answer (score 2):

You can't just use variables in strings, you need to chain them together.

So your

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Must be

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = " . $email;
```

**BUT THIS IS UNSAFE AND BAD PRACTICE!!**

You're very vunerable to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)!

You need to at least use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Take from the link this is an example how to write such querys

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for info i will look this up more. I have also made correction as Janaka suggested, and now i can process to next page (home.php) even if i put incorrect password.if($hash != $userData['password']){header("Location: home.php");}else{header("Location: index.php");}

Comment: Are you getting a result from your select? Or is it empty?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. after i put email and password, it takes me to page that i want to (home.php) but it will take me to next page even if i put incorrect email and password. I am expecting after putting incorrect information to put me back to login page(index.php).

Comment: Yeah, i understand that. What i want to know is if you can confirm that `$result` has actually the expected value after you fired the `SELECT` Statement! If there is no data the check if the data is correct will never correctly happen because there is no data to compare